# Applescript if no file is added

Tags: vim, applescript, automator

I have the following automator apple script that I'm using so that when I drag a file into a dock icon, it opens that file in vim:

```
on run {input, parameters}

set filename to POSIX path of input

    set cmd to "clear && 'vim' '" & filename & "' && exit"

    tell application "iTerm"
        set newWindow to (create window with default profile)
            tell current session of newWindow
                write text cmd
            end tell
    end tell

end run
```

However, I would also like to allow clicking the icon itself to open `vim` without any file, i.e., running $ `vim`. How would I change the above script so that:

- If a filename is passed, I open vim with that file, `vim filename`
- If no filename is passed (the icon is just double-clicked), it just opens vim, with `vim` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will do as you've asked; however, keep in mind that `input` is a *list* and as presently *coded* it is expecting a *single item list*, meaning you've only dragged and dropped one *file* onto the app's **Dock Tile**:

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}

    if not input is equal to {} then
        set filename to POSIX path of first item of input
        set cmd to "clear && 'vim' '" & filename & "' && exit"
    else
        set cmd to "clear && 'vim' '" & "' && exit"
    end if

    tell application "iTerm"
        set newWindow to (create window with default profile)
        tell current session of newWindow
            write text cmd
        end tell
    end tell

end run
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>